# Alternative to @ModelAttribute

Tags: modelattribute

I am using spring mvc for my web application.

I want alternative to @ModelAttribute.

I am setting model object in jsp file by filling form details and right now in controller i am getting it by using @ModelAttribute method parameter as mentioned below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/requestPattern")
public ModelAndView methodName(
        @ModelAttribute FormDetail formDetail,BindingResult result,
        HttpSession session) {
// I want formDetail object without using @ModelAttribute as a method argument.
}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Spring 3.X you should be able to omit @ModelAttribute and still have your FormDetail object populated.  This is the case with my application.  You can see some details here:

[Omit ModelAttribute from view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117637/spring-mvc-omit-modelattribute-from-view)