# Omit ModelAttribute from view

Tags: spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have a rest application that returns json/xml.  I use jackson and jaxb for conversion.  Some methods need to accept a query_string.  I've used @ModelAttribute to map the query_string into an object, but this forces the object into my view.  I do not want the object to appear in the view.

I think I need to use something other than @ModelAttribute, but I can't figure out how to do the binding, but not modify the view.  If I omit @ModelAttribute annotation, the object appears in the view as the variable name (eg: "sourceBundleRequest").

Example Url:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/sourcebundles/?updateDate=20100501&label=urgent
```

Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAll(@ModelAttribute("form") SourceBundleRequest sourceBundleRequest, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) throws ApiException {
    // Detect and report errors.
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
       // (omitted for clarity)
    }

    // Fetch matching data.
    PaginatedResponse<SourceBundle> sourceBundleResponse = null;
    try {
        int clientId = getRequestClientId();
        sourceBundleResponse = sourceBundleService.get(clientId, sourceBundleRequest);
    } catch (ApiServiceException e) {
        throw new ApiException(ApiErrorType.INTERNAL_ERROR, "sourceBundle fetch failed");
    }

    // Return the response.
    RestResponse<PaginatedResponse> restResponse = new RestResponse<PaginatedResponse>(200, "OK");
    restResponse.setData(sourceBundleResponse);
    model.addAttribute("resp", restResponse);
    // XXX - how do I prevent "form" from appearing in the view?
    return "restResponse";
}
```

Example Output:

```
"form": {
    "label": "urgent",
    "updateDate": 1272697200000,
    "sort": null,
    "results": 5,
    "skip": 0
},
"resp": {
    "code": 200,
    "status": "OK",
    "data": {
        "totalAvailable": 0,
        "resultList": [ ]
    }
}
```

Desired Output:

```
"resp": {
    "code": 200,
    "status": "OK",
    "data": {
        "totalAvailable": 0,
        "resultList": [ ]
    }
}
```

**Omitting @ModelAttribute("form")**

If I simply omit @ModelAttribute("form"), I still get the undesirable response but the incoming form is named by the object name.  The response looks like this:

```
"resp": {
    "code": 200,
    "status": "OK",
    "data": {
        "totalAvailable": 0,
        "resultList": [ ]
    }
},
"sourceBundleRequest": {
    "label": "urgent",
    "updateDate": 1272697200000,
    "sort": null,
    "results": 5,
    "skip": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I missed the most obvious way to fix this.  I was focused on the Attributes and forgot that I can just modify the underlying Map.

```
  // Remove the form object from the model map.
  model.remove("form");
```

It might be a little more efficient to omit @ModelAttribute as Biju suggested and then remove the sourceBundleRequest object.  I suspect @ModelAttribute has some additional overhead.

Answer (score 3):

You need not annotate the form with @ModelAttribute if you don't want the form to come back to the view, it will cleanly get bound to `SourceBundleRequest` even without the @ModelAttribute annotation.

Now, a standard way to return a JSON/XML response using Spring MVC is to return the type directly (in your case the `PaginatedResponse`) and then annotate the method with `@ResponseBody` , an underlying `HttpMessageConverter` would then transform the response into a XML/JSON based on the Accept header from the client.

```
@ResponseBody
public RestResponse<PaginatedResponse> getAll(SourceBundleRequest sourceBundleRequest, BindingResult result, ModelMap model)
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, simply omitting @ ModelAttribute doesn't work for me.  I've updated my OP with the details.  I'd prefer not to go down the @ ResponseBody route at present.  I like my explicit view mapping and don't want to get into Accept header issues.

Answer (score 0):

How about using @JsonIgnore?

```
@ModelAttribute("foo")
@JsonIgnore
public Bar getBar(){}
```

Haven't tested this